# How to call without video by linphonec?

Tags: console, call, sip, voice, linphone

I am build Linphone from official site for Debian:

```
$ ./linphone --version
linphone 4.1.1-655-g95245907

$ ./linphonec --version
version: 3.12.0
```

I am try voice call in **linphonec** to test phone, but get error:

```
> call 891********8
2019-03-06 17:13:20:391 liblinphone-error-LinphoneCore has video disabled for both capture and display, but video policy is to start the call with video. This is a possible mis-use of the API. In this case, video is disabled in default LinphoneCallParams
Error from linphone_core_invite.
```

Okay, may be enable set only voice? Yes, it is possible:

```
> help call
'call <sip-url or number>  [options]'   : initiate a call to the specified destination.
Options can be:
--audio-only : initiate the call without video.
--early-media : sends audio and video stream immediately when remote proposes early media.
```

Good option **--audio-only**. Try it:

```
> call 891********8 --audio-only
2019-03-06 17:14:01:951 liblinphone-error-LinphoneCore has video disabled for both capture and display, but video policy is to start the call with video. This is a possible mis-use of the API. In this case, video is disabled in default LinphoneCallParams
Error from linphone_core_invite.
```

This option is not work.

Q: How to disable video in default LinphoneCallParams? How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem and the solution I came up with may help.

My problem:

```
linphonec> call 5201
2019-04-13 02:47:38:771 liblinphone-error-LinphoneCore has video disabled   for both capture and display, but video policy is to start the call with video.  This is a possible mis-use of the API. In this case, video is disabled in default LinphoneCallParams
Error from linphone_core_invite.     <----- THE REAL PROBLEM
```

The solution was to include the domain. For me this was:

```
linphonec> call sip:5201@172.31.0.1
2019-04-13 02:53:00:103 liblinphone-error-LinphoneCore has video disabled for both capture and display, but video policy is to start the call with video. This is a possible mis-use of the API. In this case, video is disabled in default LinphoneCallParams
Establishing call id to sip:5201@172.31.0.1, assigned id 2
Call 2 to sip:5201@172.31.0.1 in progress.
Media streams established with sip:5201@172.31.0.1 for call 2 (audio).
```